# nant hanging when run in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, nant, mintty

I updated to cygwin 1.7.15 this afternoon and went to run the same nant script I ran successfully this morning, except that nant now hangs - no output is ever shown. I've verified nant (0.91.3881.0 alpha2) still runs in a windows cmd prompt and I've tried to `rebaseall` on cygwin without any luck.

**Edit:** In 1.7.15, nant doesn't show as a process in task manager nor Process Explorer (sysinternals).

How do I get `nant` back working in cygwin?

Comment: Workaround: Revert to 1.7.14 and nant works again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a [known bug with a fix coming](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-06/msg00136.html). There doesn't appear to be an ETA on the fix. You can work around it by reverting to Cygwin 1.7.14. Redirecting stderr and stdout doesn't work.

If you use "non-cygwin dlls" make sure you set the CYGWIN environment variable to pipe_byte ([see here for more info](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-05/msg00324.html)).