# Why would a program not like being ran from Cygwin?

Tags: .net, command-line, console, cygwin, cmd

I like using Cygwin/rxvt as my terminal of choice as cmd.exe really sucks. I have a problem with a program though in that it won't run from rxvt for most things. Basically, I can get the help text to show up, but that's about it. Everything else I tried to do ends with the program silently exiting. This program works fine from cmd.exe, what could be different about executing the program from Cygwin?

Also, just for reference, the program is a .Net program which I have source access to.

Comment: Just a guess, but if you have source code check if the program interacts with the console (other than plain `WriteLine` stuff), like setting attributes, colors, cursor position, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I live in Cygwin using .NET binaries I've written, as well as ones I have not. However, since Cygwin is a Linux emulation layer, it's possible your tool doesn't like that environment. If you have the source, debugging into why it exits is your best bet.

That being said, make sure you have configured your Cygwin installation for the running of Windows EXEs:

- Ensure you are running the latest Cygwin ([I had issues with some binaries in 1.7.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804710/nant-hanging-when-run-in-cygwin))
- Set your `CYGWIN` environment variable to 'pipe_byte' (no quotes)

Comment: I wouldn't think a program could really tell a difference though

Comment: I've made the mistake of passing in the wrong Path to a .NET exe that expects Windows but gets Unix causing all kinds of interesting gotchas...

Answer (score 0):

just a guess, but could windows paths v unix paths be the culprit?

i'd try converting any paths passed to the program to windows format with

`cygpath -w $path`

(making sure to quote them where necessary to avoid problems with spaces).